# AutoCompleteTextView from MySQL data on a fragment

Tags: android, mysql, autocompletetextview

I would like to set an `AutoCompleteTextView` with a string array, which array data comes from `MySQL` database with use of `AsyncTask`. After that JSON formatted data is parsed into string array, which name is `strArrData`. Source strings are stored in a string array. I use code below to set adapter.

```
    myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,strArrData);

    myAutoComplete.setThreshold(2);
    myAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

    new AsyncFetch().execute();
```

I got no error message, but when I tried to type first two characters a new interfaces opened with a submit button. I cannot get suggestions as automatic completion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Comment: @pskink : I see, but JSON processing is already done in my application. I would like to know more about how auto complete function should work.

Comment: then just use your JSON processing  inside `runQuery` method

Comment: @pskink : Possible strings are already loaded into string array, so I think no need to do it again.

Comment: so you load all the items from your table???

Comment: @pskink : Yes, exactly. Data is loaded, but nothing appears in AutoCompleteTextView.